# How can my character jump in the direction of the left arrow key or right key?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

this is my code. whenever i'm pressing down on left arrow key and when i press the spacebar it stops and jumps and it stops going to the left anymore(same with the right arrow key).

```
    stop();
    var Gravity = 5;
    var yLimit = 400 - char.height;
var friction = .9;
var velocity = 100;
var djctr = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, control);

function control(event:KeyboardEvent){
    if(char.y >= yLimit || djctr == 2){
        if(event.keyCode == 32 && djctr !=2){
            char.y -= velocity;
            char.x += 7;
            djctr+=2;
        }else if (event.keyCode == 32 && djctr == 2){
            char.y -= velocity * .50;
            djctr+=2;
            }

    }

    if(event.keyCode == 37){
            char.x -= 7;
    }else if(event.keyCode == 39){
            char.x += 7;
    }
    }

function entFrame(e:Event){
    char.y += Gravity;
    if(char.y >= yLimit){
        char.y = 400-char.height;
        djctr = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do for movement control is by having two stage KeyboardEvent listeners (KEY_DOWN and KEY_UP), and a Timer that runs every frame. The keyboard events don't handle control, they only handle changing static values such as `keyLeftIsDown` and `keyRightIsDown` (in your case you can also handle when the spacebar is pressed), and the Timer listener is what handles control. This is what it might look like:

```
private var keyLeftIsDown:Boolean;
private var keyRightIsDown:Boolean;

//The '60' in '1000 / 60' is the frames per second the program runs in. Change it as needed
private var movementTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000 / 60);

private function initialize():void {
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, movementUpdate);
    timer.start();
}

private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        keyLeftIsDown = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        keyRightIsDown = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        //jump code goes here
    }
}

private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        keyLeftIsDown = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        keyRightIsDown = false;
    }
}

private function movementUpdate(e:TimerEvent):void {
    if (keyLeftIsDown && !keyRightIsDown) {
        char.x -= char.speed;
    }
    else if (keyRightIsDown && !keyLeftIsDown) {
        char.x += char.speed;
    }
}
```

This way the character moves in the x direction even if the code is handling jumps!